# php script to read and save web page contents not working on some sites

Tags: php

I have a very simple script that works perfectly on most sites but not the main site I want it to work with - the code below accesses a sample site perfectly.  However when I use it on a site I want to access http://www.livescore.com I get an error

This works.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.cambodia.me.uk";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$outfile = "contents.html";
file_put_contents($outfile, $page);
?>
```

This does not work.....

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.livescore.com";
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$outfile = "contents.html";
file_put_contents($outfile, $page);
?>
```

and gives the following error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.livescore.com)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\Livescore\attempt-1-read-page.php on line 3

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Try `http://www.livescore.com/`

Comment: Yes I have tried that - no good :-)

Comment: OK I don't know if this helps but I tried this code I found on Stackoverflow, it doesn't work but I got the following error which may help - I hope

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Server: nginx Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2016 08:58:20 GMT Location: http://www.livescore.com/ Cache-Control: no-cache content-length: 0 Connection: close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common case you can just say to `file_get_contents` to follow redirects:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => true
        )
    )
);

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

---

This site tries to analyze `User-agent` http header, and fails if it's not found. Try to add some `user-agent` header:

```
<?php

$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "User-agent: chrome",
            'ignore_errors' => true,
            'follow_location' => true
        )
    )
);

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.livescore.com/', false, $context);

echo substr($html, 0, 200)."\n";
```

Comment: Works with all sites I tried except livescore.com :-(

Comment: `User-agent` required by `livescore`.

Comment: Hi vp_arth sorry I am not sure what that means

Comment: vp_arth sorry - yes I get what you mean.  I managed to get it partly working with curl and setting the user agent.  Then I also added referrer and works perfectly - thanks for the info and advice.  I am new to stackoverflow so I am not sure how I accept your answer or close the question.  Thanks to everybody :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely www.livescore.com is doing a hidden redirect which file_get_contents is too basic to catch.

Do you have `lynx` installed on your server?

```
$page= shell_exec("lynx -source 'http://www.livescore.com'");
```

`lynx` is a full browser and can 'bypass' certain redirects.

Comment: It is shared hosting so I am not sure so will just try it and see thankyou

Comment: Tried this but I don't think lynx is installed - I do not get an error but return string is empty for all sites tried :-(